# Disable Remote Desktop NLA on local network

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have my computer set up for remote desktop over internet in NLA mode.
I also want be able to connect with iPad to my computer when im at home, but that isnt possible with NLA activated, unless i pay for some damn expensive apps which i wont.

Is there any way to configure the computer to allow non-NLA connections to my computer if they come from the local network, or do i have to disable NLA completly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to disable NLA, or else pay big bucks for it. Why have the security turned on, then not use it?

Comment: well, security would be turned on.. just not when the connection comes from the local network (192.168.0.*). That was my idea atleast. but guess thats not possible then.

Comment: @trembon Thanks for the accept. Feel free to upvote as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is Windows 7,Right Click on

> Computer -->Remote Settings -->Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop